# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable I dont understand what that means

Tags: python, replit

```
from replit import db
import os

def clear():
    del db["hits"]
    del db["ab"]

def save():
    db["hits"] = hits
    db["ab"] = ab

try:
    hits = db["hits"]
    ab = db["ab"]
    avg = hits/ab
    print(f"You're currently batting {avg}")
    
except:
    hits = 0
    ab = 0

input = input("press ENTER to continue.")
os.system("clear")

if input == clear:
    clear()
else:
#the line of code below is the one in question
    today_ab = input("How many at bats did you have today?")
    ab += today_ab
```

The last line is where it is wrong.

Comment: The problematic line is: `input = input("press ENTER to continue.")`; here you assign to `input` and hence shadow the builtin function with that name; later you attempt to use it however which then fails since `input` now is a string.

Comment: The error says that you're trying to use a string as a function. If your read your code carefully, you're creating an `input` variable that contains a string. This collides with the built-in function named `input`. So at the end of your script you're using the string instead of the function. Just rename your variable to avoid this naming collision

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't have separate namespaces for variables and functions. This line

```
input = input("press ENTER to continue.")
```

replaces the built-in function `input` with the result of the call. When you try to call `input` later, you get the `TypeError`.

Use a different variable name:

```
x = input("press ENTER to continue.")

if x == "clear":
    clear()
```